# Is PHPMailer Secure

Tags: php, phpmailer

I know this probably isn't an easy question but I'm developing several webforms and want a PHP library that I can use to send the mail and have it automatically sanitize the data.  I was looking at PHPMailer which looked pretty simple to setup.

Is PHPMailer a secure library to use to prevent my forms from being subject to SQL Injection/E-mail Injection / XSS, etc?  I recognize nothing is 100% secure but I'm looking for an easy script to use without me having to sanitize the data.

Comment: It depends on where this email is going to be displayed. You should only allow plain text mails (my personal opinion, I hate html mails). More important is that you don't allow spam abusing your frontends as a spam gateway, so only allow for example 1 mail per minute per IP/cookie/... and no arbitary receivers.

Comment: Disable immediately today your phpmailer if your cms use it at this date until security patch has not been released:
https://legalhackers.com/advisories/PHPMailer-Exploit-Remote-Code-Exec-CVE-2016-10033-Vuln.html

Answer (score 4):

PHPMailer doesn't create/use any SQL itself, nor does it have anything to do with javascript, so it's secure on those fronts. It is often used alongside code that does both, but that's not PHPMailer's concern.

It applies filtering to headers in order to avoid header injection attacks, and (as far as I'm aware!) builds headers correctly in order to escape and encode according to RFCs - generally PHPMailer favours strict technical compliance where practical. There is one open issue relating to line length compliance.

If run with PHP 5.6 using default settings, it verifies SSL/TLS certificates on secure connections. Earlier PHP versions don't do this by default, and you can disable it in PHP 5.6, though neither is recommended. There is an open issue relating to forcing this setting in earlier PHP versions.

All that said, of course PHPMailer (like any technical library) can be abused to send all kinds of nasty phishing, spam and malware, and the SMTP class can be used to try to confuse the hell out of mail servers, though it will try its hardest to ensure it does so with the utmost respect for the RFCs.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I wasn't sure if SQL injection should still be something I should be concerned about (e.g. if hackers were able to guess a db username/password and inputted the right code to make a database connection).  I got the impression PHPMailer did a good job ensuring things were escaped and handling header injection but just wanted to get another opinion.  Thanks again.

Comment: If a user guessed a DB username and password, injection would be the least of your worries. You can make a database connection with some 3rd party software.

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is a highly recommended patch for vulnerabilities for Versions before 5.2.18 
Download here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

The quote from Hacker News (http://thehackernews.com/2016/12/phpmailer-security.html) gives a brief summary:

> Discovered by Polish security researcher Dawid Golunski of Legal
>   Hackers, the critical vulnerability (CVE-2016-10033) allows an
>   attacker to remotely execute arbitrary code in the context of the web
>   server and compromise the target web application.
>
> "To exploit the vulnerability an attacker could target common website components such
>   as contact/feedback forms, registration forms, password email resets
>   and others that send out emails with the help of a vulnerable version
>   of the PHPMailer class," Golunski writes in the advisory published
>   today.

The technical details will be posted here: https://legalhackers.com/papers/Pwning-PHP-mail-func-For-Fun-And-RCE-New-Exploit-Techniques-Vectors.html